# Sharepoint and Github synchronization

Tags: github, sharepoint, synchronization

is there any way to synchronize data between Sharepoint and Github? Users would work in Sahrepoint and it would sync with Github. Automatic synchronization at a certain time would be best, but there should also be the possibility of manual synchronization. Thank you.

I have no big experiences and no ideas how to do it.